# Create filter queries by hand using elasticsearch_dsl

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to build arbitrary nested queries stored in a some data structures (possibly a tree). 
[From the manual](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#filters) I gather that `filter` type of queries are special types of `Bool` queries, so that

```
s = Search()
s = s.filter('terms', tags=['search', 'python'])
```

and

```
s = Search()
s = s.query('bool', filter=[Q('terms', tags=['search', 'python'])])
```

are the same.
I tried this on my query, but something is not working properly.

This first query works and returns the expected results:

```
s = Search(using=client, index='index')
s = s.filter('term', some_field=some_value)
print(s.to_dict())

>>> {'query': {'filtered': {'filter': {'term': {'some_field': 'some_value'}}, \
     'query': {'match_all': {}}}}}
```

Mimicking the example in the query does not seem to work:

```
s = Search(using=client, index='index')
s = s.query(Q('bool', filter=[Q('term', some_field=some_value])]))
print(s.to_dict())
>>> {'query': {'bool': {'filter': [{'term': {some_field': some_value}}]}}
```

Note that I am using version 1 of ElasticSearch because for some reason AWS has not upgraded yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ES 1.x, then you cannot use the second way, i.e. the one that yields a `bool/filter` query.

If you get that query, that means you're using elasticsearch-dsl 2.x or later, [which is not correct](http://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#compatibility).

You need to modify your `requirements.txt` file to include this

```
# Elasticsearch 1.x
elasticsearch-dsl<2.0.0
```

Comment: From the link you sent, 'The library is compatible with all Elasticsearch versions since 1.x but you have to use a matching major version:', which I am already using. It doesn't say that `bool/filter` is not supported for `1.x` version

Comment: `bool/filter` has been introduced in ES 2.x so I can guarantee you that it is not supported for 1.x version

Comment: Not yet. I reverted to the pure json queries for now. Also I might misunderstood your comment, but I think that `bool/filters` where in `1.x` version too? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/query-dsl-filtered-query.html